# Cordova/Phonegap - Does beforeunload work or any alternatives?

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, onbeforeunload

So I have a client object I want to write to a file before the app is killed.  Does anyone know if the browser beforeunload event works for that purpose?  Or does Cordova have a native way to handle that condition?

I know there are the "pause" and "resume" events, but I'm not sure if those handle the "kill" event as well.  I can't seem to find any documentation on this anywhere.

If anyone can point to the right direction of have a recommendation it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a little bit more digging and some trial and error, I guess the proper way to handle this is to listen to the "pause" event I mentioned in my question.  It seems to fire every time the user even pulls up the menu to kill the app.  It should work then for my purposes.

```
document.addEventListener("pause", function () {
    app.inBackground = true;
    app.saveData();
}, false);
```

I'm not sure if it follows any standard or there is a better way to do it, so if anyone else has more info, feel free to leave it here.